# Compute raster statistics on sequential list of raster layers

Tags: r, raster, r-raster

Suppose I have a `rasterstack` consisting of 5 layers:

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(nrows=10,ncols=10)
r[] <- rnorm(100)
stk <- stack(r,r*2,r+10,r-7, r*6)
```

I would like to compute a statistic on a sequential set of the layers based on a different list of numbers.

```
my.seq<-as.numeric(c("2", "1", "2"))
```

How can I compute a statistic (e.g. mean) for:

Layers 1:2 in `s` i.e. my.seq[1]

Layer 3 in `s` i.e. my.seq[2]

Layers 4:5 in `s` i.e. my.seq[3]

I feel this would be best achieved using a loop but I cannot work out how this would work.

Any help would be gratefully received.

---

EDIT

This is what I'm trying to do IRL. I thought I would include it here to help give the question greater context.

I'm trying to compute monthly means from daily temperature data. The rasterstack I'm working with has hundreds of layers, one for every day of the month in sequence. So the layers 1:31 are, when taken together, January 1970. In the above example, `my.seq` is a list containing the number of days in each month. So I'm trying compute the mean for days 1:31 (January) then 32:60 (February) etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `stackApply` for that

Example data

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(nrows=10, ncols=10, vals=rnorm(100))
stk <- stack(r,r*2,r+10,r-7, r*6)
my.seq <- c(2, 1, 2)
```

Get the indices and use `stackApply`

```
i <- rep(1:length(my.seq), my.seq)
x <- stackApply(stk, i, fun='mean')
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand your example of `my.seq` in regard to what you explain in wanting different raster subsets. Here is a worked example where I create a list object with your defined subsets. All you need to do is pass the desired numeric index of subset of rasters to a double bracket index of the stack object. The list object has to be subset using a double bracket as well so, it looks a mess `s[[idx[[i]]]]`. However, if you break it down, for the first raster subset, it is merely: `raster::calc(s[[1:2]], mean)`

```
library(raster)
file <- system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster")
s <- stack(file, file, file)
s <- addLayer(s, raster(file)/2, raster(file)*2)

idx <- list( c(1:2), c(3), c(4:5) )
s.mean <- stack()
  for(i in 1:length(idx)) {
    s.mean <- addLayer(s.mean, calc(s[[idx[[i]]]], mean) )
  }

s.mean
plot(s.mean)
```

In relation to your expanded question, you can use the date class in R to create indices and even more conveniently, the rts package allows for these types of time-series summaries.

Here, let's create a stack with 365 layers representing days of the year.

```
library(raster)
f <- raster(nrows=50, ncols=50, xmn=0, xmx=10)
s <- stack()
  for(i in 1:365) {
    x <- f
    x[] <- runif(ncell(x),0,10)
    s <- addLayer(s, x)
}
```

Now, we can create the corresponding dates vector.

```
( d <- seq(as.Date("1970/1/1"), as.Date("1970/12/31"), "days") )
```

The dates vector can be queried to provide a raster index. Say we want the mean for December, we can use `which` to produce the index.

```
( dec.idx <- which( months(d) == "December") )
( dec.mean <- calc(s[[dec.idx]], mean) )
```

You can easily create a list containing the raster stack indices for each month which would be equivalent to what you describe in your my.seq object.

```
months.idx <- list()   
  for(m in unique( months(d) ) ) {
    months.idx[[m]] <- which( months(d) == m)  
  }  
months.idx
```

However, this is built in functionality to perform these type of temporal summaries in the rts package so, we can shortcut any for loop by coercing the stack to an rts object and then using one of the apply function.

```
library(rts)
s.date <- rts::rts(s, d)
( s.month <- apply.monthly(s.date, mean) )
```

Comment: IRL I'm trying to compute monthly means from daily temperature data. The rasterstack I'm working with has hundreds of layers, one for every day of the month. In the above example, my.seq is a list containing the number of days in each month. So I'm trying compute the mean for days 1:31 (January) then 32:60 (February) etc. 

I guess in your response above, the key is generating "idx" automatically. It's obviously easy to do this when there are only three splits but something different entirely for 100+ splits.

Comment: You really should have clarified this in your question as, I would have been able to provide a more relevant answer. You can use R's date class to easily create the relevant indices from the data ranges, including leap years. Take a look at the rts package as it has functionality for summaries by week, month, quarter, year, etc... BTW, your my.seq object is a vector not a list and, yes terminology matters because these are two different object classes. We try to put your example code in the context of your question and in this case it is nonsensical in relation to your desired outcome.

Comment: I appreciate the response, it has been a long day. However I would counter that my reproducible code makes it clear what I'm trying to do, regardless as to whether I accidentally typed list instead of vector.

Comment: I shall check out the rts package now though - it looks super useful and one I haven't heard of before. Thank you for showing me this, it's much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This function uses `my.seq` to extract the layers of interest (including potentially repeated layers, as in the example).

You can put them into a new `stack` or compute/combine stats on the layer-level in the part of the code below that extracts them.

```
new_stack <- function(x){
  tmp <- stack()
  for(i in x){
    new <- stk[[i]]
    tmp <- stack(tmp, new)  
  }
  return(tmp)
}

tmp2 <- new_stack(my.seq)
```

Now, I wasn't 100% sure what precisely how you wanted the mean computed, so I did it several ways below:

```
stack_mean <- function(x){
  tmp         <- stack()
  layer_means <- numeric()

  for(i in x){
    new <- stk[[i]]

    layer_mean <- mean(stk[[i]]@data@values) 
    print(paste("In layer ", i, "the layer mean is ", layer_mean))

    layer_means <- c(layer_means, layer_mean)

    tmp <- stack(tmp, new)  

  }
  print(paste("Mean of means:", mean(layer_means)))
  return(tmp)
}

stack_mean(my.seq)
```

This computes several means. First, the means of the layers (which I know is *not* what you want - I'm just showing how for posterity):

> ```
> [1] "In layer  2 the layer mean is  -0.0981706786020096"
> [1] "In layer  1 the layer mean is  -0.0490853393010048"
> [1] "In layer  2 the layer mean is  -0.0981706786020096"
> ```

Then the mean of the 3 layers together:

> ```
> [1] "Mean of means: -0.081808898835008"
> ```

Finally, you have the mean of the `stack` object, which is apparently a thing though I don't know much about this and have no idea what all this really means:

`mean(tmp2) # equivalently: mean(stack_means(my.seq))`

> ```
> class       : RasterLayer 
> dimensions  : 10, 10, 100  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
> resolution  : 36, 18  (x, y)
> extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
> coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 
> data source : in memory
> names       : layer 
> values      : -5.742679, 4.206359  (min, max)
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm not trying to compute a mean on each layer, rather, I need to compute statistics based on a pre-defined set (sequential) of layers. My comment above to Jeffery Evans explains what I'm trying to do in real life - hopefully this will help with a solution.

Comment: Thank you for updating your answer. Having very quickly gone through the first bit of code, it seems to be doing what I need: it takes a rasterstack and then splits it up sequentially. Please allow me time to run this on my real data to ensure that I get the expected behaviour.

Comment: @Simon sure, let me know how it goes

Comment: I would comment that calling slots directly (eg., stk[[i]]@data@values) forces the raster package to read the raster into memory and causes the problem to not be memory safe. This can really matter for time-series data. There is no need to coerce the raster to a vector as you can just use the double bracket index to subset the stack. The memory safe alternative for a global mean would be: raster::cellStats

Comment: @Hack-R thanks for your response to my question. I have accepted RObert's answer as there was already a function within 'raster' that will enable me to carry out the job. The package is so big and comprehensive that it's easy to miss a key function like this! Thanks again for your help.